# Why is aggregation function bad idea for RESTful?

Tags: rest, aggregate-functions

As title: Why is aggregation function bad idea for RESTful? Although I know CRUD is good for RESTful.

For example, the resource is '*employee*', and client needs to retrive sum of total '*salary*' of all employees. Shouldn't RESTful service provide such sum function?

Further question: if aggregation function is bad for RESTful, how can a client get sum of total salary? To retrieve all '*employee*' records and sum up itself?

Comment: do you need any more help on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wouldn't say that exposing the results of operations (i.e. an aggregation function) as resources in REST has to be considered as bad.

From the [RESTful Webservices Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801694.do) (O'Reilly):

> One of the most common perceptions of REST’s architectural constraints is that they
>   only apply to resources that are “things” or “entities” in the application domain. Although
>   this may be true in a number of cases, scenarios that involve processing functions
>   challenge that perception.

It is quite common to treat a processing function as a resource, and use HTTP GET to fetch a representation containing the output of the processing function. You can also use query parameters to supply inputs to the processing function.

So why not provide the result of a salary aggregation of a number of employees as a resource, i.e. like this:

```
GET /employees/aggregation?data=salary
```

or more general:

```
GET /aggregator?resource=employee&data=salary
```

You could even filter the group of employees for which the salaries should be aggregated, i.e. like this:

```
GET /employees/aggregation?data=salary&divison=sales
```